# How can i create a trigger in azure data factory that only trigger once only

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The pipeline I need to run on specific start time but there is no end time I need to create it to run one time

Comment: Hey, Can you be little clear about your ask here? Do you mean to trigger the pipeline in an automated way only once and disable it?

Comment: Hi Nandan, yes Nandan we have to trigger at the particular time only once. After successfull of the pipeline it has to stop

Comment: Please ask if any other info needed thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please create a scheduled trigger with an end date :

[image]

The end date would ensure that the trigger is disabled

Comment: Thanks for the solution we will test if any doubts please help us..